# How to debug child and parent process using windbg?

Tags: debugging, command, windbg, createprocess, child-process

I have one program which creates the child process using CreateProcess function. While Debugging, I step into child process by **childdbg 1** . But after executing whole steps of child process. It doesn't returned to Parent process.

When I use .childdbg 1

> 0:000> .childdbg 1
>   Processes created by the current process will be debugged

then i used 2 time g, 
first time, it loaded modules and come to, below position,

> 0:000> g
>   
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   
>   1:002>

2nd time, once again it loaded some other modules, and come to below position,

> 1:002> g
>   
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   
>   2:005>

From this point, I will start debug my child process. Its working good. After, running child process, its directly execute it parent process. So, can anyone give me the **debug command or command** to come out from second process to 1st process. Please, I need debug level solution. Not from my code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [|](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566242.aspx) command to verify the processes currently attached to. Similar to switching between threads (~0s, ~1s, ~2s), you may use [|0s |1s |2s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565423.aspx) etc to switch between attached processes.

Comment: Ok. Its coming to parent process. Here, I have one doubt. If, I switch from child process to parent process, then child process will finish its all steps or just it will hang on that step ?

Comment: This saved my life! I want to up vote this answer 10 times if I can.

Answer (score 3):

.childdbg 1 enables debugging of the first child only and not the grandchild
in your example 2.002 is a grandchild
to debug it and then come back to child you need to issue .childdbg 1 on every generation

```
childdbg:\>dir /b
childdbg.cpp

childdbg:\>type childdbg.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main (void)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL, "childdbg.exe", NULL, NULL, 
    FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si, &pi ) )
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return 0;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    return 0;
}
childdbg:\>cl /Zi /nologo childdbg.cpp
childdbg.cpp

childdbg:\>dir /b *.exe
childdbg.exe

do not run the exe it will spawn zillion childs
use debugger and when done subvert flow to skip child creation


childdbg:\>cdb childdbg.exe

0:000> .childdbg 1
Processes created by the current process will be debugged
0:000> g

1:001> .childdbg 1
Processes created by the current process will be debugged
1:001> g

2:002> .childdbg 1
Processes created by the current process will be debugged
2:002> g

3:003> .childdbg 1
Processes created by the current process will be debugged
3:003> g

4:004> lsf childdbg.cpp
childdbg.cpp
4:004> bp childdbg!main
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for childdbg.exe
4:004> g

Breakpoint 0 hit

childdbg!main:
00401010 55              push    ebp

4:004> ls 10
    10:     if( !CreateProcess( NULL, "childdbg.exe", NULL, NULL,
                FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi ) )
    11:     {
    12:         printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    13:         return 0;
    14:     }
    15:     WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    16:     CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    17:     CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    18:     return 0;
    19: }
4:004> r eip = `:18`
WARNING: Line information loading disabled
4:004> .lines
Line number information will be loaded
4:004> r eip = `:18`
4:004> r
childdbg!main+0x8a:
0040109a 33c0            xor     eax,eax
4:004> g
4:004> g
3:003> g
2:002> g
1:001> g
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
0:000> q
quit:
childdbg:\>
```